# Get slider thumb absolute position with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shadow-dom

I have an `input type=range` slider which represents the progress bar for a video. This slider is wrapped inside a smaller container so that when the thumb on the slider reaches the edge of the container, the container scrolls left enough to make the thumb visible again. Thus I need to detect when this happens. I can't use the timeupdate event of the video, because it also fires after clicking the slider, but in this case the container should not scroll. I also cannot use the jQueryUI slider because it's less precise than the HTML one...

I think I need to find a way to detect the actual position in pixel of the thumb. Which unfortunately is a shadow DOM element... Is there a way to get it with javascript/jquery?

UPDATE: This is how Chrome renders the `<input type=range>` DOM element, as it is shown in the Developer Tools:

```
<input type="range">
  #shadow-root
    <div>  --> This is the slider container
      <div>  --> This is the slider track
        <div></div>  --> This is the slider thumb
      </div>
      <div style="visibility: hidden; position: static;"></div>
    </div>
</input>
```

What I want to do is detect the position (absolute or relative) of the slider thumb div without looking for its value.

Comment: Why can't you increase the width of the parent container? And is there some code?

Comment: As this case is dependent on you implementation no one can really help you unless you provide some code.

Comment: Mmh I probably explained myself badly (sorry, but my english isn't quite perfect ^_^), I'm not looking for a workaround, and what I'm trying to do doesn't depend on my implementation. At least I don't think so. I'll update the question anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You could show some code I don't fully understand what you're trying to do...

With jQuery try binding the shadow element like that :

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="range"]', function(e) {
    var left = $('#imgId').position().left,
        rangePosition = $(this).val();
});
```